# Create new file for each instance Python

Tags: python, text, python-3.x, split

I have a file with id numbers along with the specifics on event that is logged. (time, temp, location)

I want python to group all of the same i.d.'s into their own unique files, storing all of the even specifics from each record.

That is to say go through each record, if the id does not have a log file create one, if it does log the new record into that id's file.

Example input

```
1, 11:00, 70, port A
1, 11:02, 70, port B
2, 11:00, 40, blink
3, 11:00, 30, front
```

Desired output

file name "1" with :[11:00, 70, port A ;
                     11:02, 70, port B ]

file name "2" with :[11:00, 40, blink]

file name "3" with :[11:00, 30, front]

I am very new to python and I am having trouble finding a reference guide. If anyone knows a good place where I can look for an answer I would appreciate it.

Comment: "I am very new to python and I am having trouble finding a reference guide" - no you just haven't tried very hard.

Comment: Give it a try, and paste some code. The community would be happy to help in improving your code.

Comment: @legoStormtroopr was that really necessary? Flag it if you think the question is not deserving of posting but don't bash someone who is at least smart enough to get this far.

Comment: @PyNEwbie Had they shown any effort I would have been nicer, however there is no code and a simple search for ["Python write file"](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=python+write+file) turns up dozens of links that would have helped them *write at least some code.*

Comment: Well I have no desire to get into a war with you.  Clearly the person is new to this and so I just wonder why sarcasm is necessary look at @SunnyNanda's response - This is a small world and beating up someone because they don't know the rules looks mean.  Further if you look back you will see that when SO first started out there are plenty of questions similar to this one.  As it has developed more people have gotten less patient with the new folks.

Comment: @PyNEwbie : There was no intended sarcasm in my comment. It was an honest attempt to prompt OP to try. After all, We all have been there, right?

Comment: @SunnyNanda I am sorry I was holding out your comment as a much more polite way to respond instead of the sarcasm in the other.  I am sorry  for the confusiuon.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward - presuming your file is as you described it however I am in Python 2.7 so I am not sure what the differences could be.

```
all_lines = open('c:\\path_to_my_file.txt').readlines()
from collections import defaultdict
my_classified_lines = defaultdict(list)
for line in all_lines:
    data_type, value1,value2,value3 = line.split(',')
    my_classified_lines[data_type).append(','.join([value1,value2,value3])


for data_type in my_classified_lines:
    outref = open('c:\\directory\\' + data_type + '.txt', 'w')
    outref.writelines(my_classified_lines[data_type])
    outref.close()
```

to understand this you need to learn about dictionaries - useful containers for data,
file operations
and loops

I found Dive into Python a great resource when I was starting up

I may not have exactly what you want after looking at your output mine would be like

11:00, 70, port A 
11:02, 70, port B

I think you are stating that you want a list like object with semi-colons as the separator  which to me suggests you are asking for a string with brackets around it.  If your output is really as you describe it then try this

```
for data_type in my_classified_lines:
    outref = open('c:\\directory\\' + data_type + '.txt', 'w')
    out_list =[ ';'.join([item for item in my_classified_lines[data_type'])]
    outref.writelines(outlist) # should be only one line
    outref.close()
```